# Geo Location - Using Ionic Framework, AngularJS and Google API

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

We are trying to using this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt) within our latest [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)/[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) project and can't seem to figure this issue out.

We want to be able to click 'Find Us' and have the [Google Map Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) display our current location.

If anyone can see where we're going wrong please let us know.
Thank you.

```
// Google Map
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
  function initialise() {   
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.068165,-4.076803);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15, 
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
      }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
    });
    $scope.map = map;    
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }
    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      showBackdrop: true
    });
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, 
    function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };
 });
```

[image]

Comment: The javascript/HTML you posted works for me (shows a marker).  The issue must be in the framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a good example of this.

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/bwdoA)

```
.controller('MarkerRemoveCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

  $scope.positions = [{
    lat: 43.07493,
    lng: -89.381388
  }];

  $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
    $scope.map = map;
  });

  $scope.centerOnMe= function(){

    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...'
    });


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      $scope.positions.push({lat: pos.k,lng: pos.B});
      console.log(pos);
      $scope.map.setCenter(pos);
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

  };

});
```

I did use a directive for google maps, just to keep everything in angular-land.

Comment: Why `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't work in android emulator?

Comment: @evc Did you find any solution for android?

Comment: @EmptyData It works, don't use cordova plugin, but only ask for geolocation permissions, then android will give browser native geolocation service

Comment: @evc How to ask for permission in hybrid app?

Comment: You need 1 plugin at least, lets say camera, install it by cordova add  plugin [name]. It will be installed in plugins folder, open android.json and add permissions after the camera permission

Comment: Can you tell me how to add permission in my ionic app

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [`CodePen`](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt) of an Ionic app with Google Maps

---

```
angular.module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])

    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

        //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
        var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: compiled[0]
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        $scope.map = map;
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
        if(!$scope.map) {
          return;
        }

        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
          content: 'Getting current location...',
          showBackdrop: false
        });

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
          $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
          $scope.loading.hide();
        }, function(error) {
          alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
        });
      };

      $scope.clickTest = function() {
        alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
      };

    });
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question itself, not just a link to an external resource.

Comment: @geocodezip In the CodePen you have all the app working, but I have edit my answer and you can see the MapCtrl

Answer (score 0):

```
when you find the current location of your phone first you find out the latitude and longitude.So First,Add the plugin your project 
1.cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

2.module.controller('GeoCtrl', function($cordovaGeolocation,$http) {

  var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude //here you get latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude //here you get the longitude
  $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+long+'&sensor=true').then(function(data){      $rootScope.CurrentLocation=data.data.results[0].formatted_address;//you get the current location here


        }, function(err) {
          // error
        });
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });

}):
```